# Can single python process use two or more native threads simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

As I read somewhere on internet that single python process can not use more than one native thread simultaneously. Why?

Answer (score 1):

jython doesn't have a GIL, so is able to use native threads effectively

The GIL remains in CPython because usually the overhead of finegrained locking defeats the advantage of multiple threads.

C extensions such as numpy and numexpr, can also utilise multithreading.